# Default values for updatable views in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, updatable-views

Lets say I have something like the following:

```
create table tab
(
  data varchar2(100),
  source number
);

create view source_1 as
(
  select data from tab where source = 1
);

create view source_2 as
(
  select data from tab where source = 2
);
```

I want

```
insert into source_1 values ( 'hello' );
```

to insert `( 'hello', 1 )` into `tab`.

And similarly:

```
insert into source_2 values ( 'hello' );
```

to insert `( 'hello', 2 )` into `tab`.

I know I could use default values on the table if there was only one view, but that won't work for two views.

Is there anyway to do this other than `instead of insert` triggers on each of the views?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is still a view and not a table. Views do not support default values as they are logical entities and not physical ones like tables.